# How to find a process of the current user in Perl using WMI

Tags: perl, process, wmi

**Scenario**: I want to check if a given process is running, and if so then wait for it to close.

My Perl script is using WMI-->Win32_Process to get the list of running process. I am able to find the running process with the below code

```
my $objWMIService = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\localhost\\root\\CIMV2");
my $sqry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where Name = \"$processName\" ";`
```

where `$processName` is set in the script.

The above code works fine on desktops but the code works in a different way in terminal servers because it the above code pick's up other user's running process.

**Question**: How can I add a username/id filter in the above query? Is there any easy way to get the process for current user?

Comment: You should show us how `$processName` is set. Maybe it becomes more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which WMI module are you using? It sounds like `DBD::WMI`.

Comment: `$processName` is the my application name..for argument sake we can keep it as outlook.exe

Comment: @Borodin update the code..i am using Win32

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution (workaround at least)..in case any one is interested..

```
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
my $useridval;  
my ($strUser, $strDomain) = (   Variant(VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF, '<undef>'),   Variant(VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF, '<undef>')    );
foreach my $objItem (in $colItems) {
    $useridval = $objItem->GetOwner($strUser, $strDomain);
    if (length($useridval) > 0) {
    if ($useridval == 0 ){
        print ("Process " . $objItem->{Name} . " id: " . $objItem->{ProcessId} . " session id: " . $objItem->{SessionId}) . " owner: " . $strUser->Value . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: added modified code as the simple variable didn't work. I've removed all error checking to keep it simple

thank you all

Comment: Does this work? I thought `GetOwner` needed variants as paremeters and I am surprised if it works with bare Perl variables.