# I can't get proper Name&Domain properties using Win32_Process::GetOwner call under Perl

Tags: perl, wmi

I want to enumerate all running  processes' name&domain propeties using Win32_Process::GetOwner method under Perl, my code was listed below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE('in');
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $retval;
my $machine = ".";
my $outParam;
my $CLASS = "Winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\\\$machine\\root\\cimv2";
my $WMI = Win32::OLE->GetObject($CLASS) or die("GetObject:" . Win32::OLE->LastError());
my $process = $WMI->InstancesOf("Win32_Process");

my $vtName = Win32::OLE::Variant->new(VT_CY, VT_EMPTY);
my $vtDomain = Win32::OLE::Variant->new(VT_CY, VT_EMPTY);
foreach my $obj(in $process)
{
    $retval = $obj->GetOwner($vtName, $vtDomain);
    if($retval == 0){
        print $vtName->Value() . "\t" . $vtDomain->Value() . "\n";
    }
}
```

The script can run properly, but I got the "zero" echo string everytime:

[image: echo]

Who can tell me what caused this problem and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems Karthik already has the [code you're looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257565/how-to-find-a-process-of-the-current-user-in-perl-using-wmi) for:

```
my $objWMIService = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\localhost\\root\\CIMV2");
my $sqry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where Name = \"$processName\" ";`
```

Also seems someone else has the same issue where Perl issues a status code of 0 instead of the actual data:
http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/16230/